# Use local jar files in IBM Analytics Engine

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, hortonworks-data-platform, analytics-engine

I'm trying to falimiarise myself with IBM Analytics Engine. I've managed to create a service and run an example application. I now wish to see how one of my applications runs on it. For this I need two jars(which currently sit on my Mac). I tried to scp them to the jars folder in my Analytics Engine but got a permission denied. How can I use these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have any trouble scp-ing into my home directory of my master node:

```
scp hello-world.jar clsadmin@xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx.bi.services.us-south.bluemix.net:/home/wce/clsadmin/
```

I was able to run using spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class HelloWorld /home/wce/clsadmin/hello-world.jar
```

Are you trying to copy into your home directory, or another directory?

Comment: I was trying to copy to another directory but have since managed to copy to my home. Couldn't get spark-submit to run though. I'll take another look at it tomorrow. Perhaps I made some mistake.